# Computing the equivariant cohomology class of a Białynicki-Birula cell

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-combinatorics, computational-topology

One of my current research interests is Hessenberg varieties. Briefly, if $m_1\le m_2\le \cdots \le m_{n-1}$ is a weakly increasing sequence of positive integers such that $i\le m_i\le n$ for all $i$, and $s:\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is a linear transformation, then the associated Hessenberg variety comprises all complete flags $F_1 \subseteq F_2\subseteq \cdots \subseteq F_n$ such that $sF_i \subseteq F_{m_i}$ for all $i$.  There is a torus action so we can speak of equivariant cohomology. Goresky–Kottwitz–MacPherson theory applies and so we can explicitly specify an equivariant cohomology class by specifying a polynomial for each vertex of the moment graph.

We also have a Białynicki-Birula decomposition.  I was hoping to write some computer code that would, for small examples, explicitly compute the equivariant cohomology classes associated to closures of BB cells.  Unfortunately, this seems to be difficult because of the singularities that arise.  In very small cases, hand computation is possible using ad hoc arguments, but is there a general algorithm for performing this computation?

Comment: Of course, $s:{\mathbb C}^n\rightarrow {\mathbb C}^n$. Do you only consider Hessenberg varieties of type A?

Comment: @FZaldivar : Thanks, I corrected the typo. I am primarily interested in type A but have some interest in other types.

Comment: I don't know an implementation, but I think the methods used in Tymoczko's "Permutation representations on Schubert varieties" (Section 2) and Guillemin-Zara's "The existence of generating families for the cohomology ring of a graph" (also Section 2) can be translated into an algorithm of the kind you want.  (Possibly with some nontrivial work.)

Comment: @DaveAnderson : Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to me that those methods produce some kind of basis for equivariant cohomology, but not necessarily the one coming from Białynicki-Birula. In fact part of my motivation is that Tymoczko's recipe seems to involve some arbitrary choices and I suspect that the "best" choices might correspond to BB. But to verify that, I need some independent way to compute BB.

Comment: Does Lemma 1 in Section 2 of "Puzzles and equivariant cohomology of Grassmannians" by Knutsen and Tao (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0112150.pdf) help? The basic observation (which you have probably already made) is that under a GKM condition there is a unique basis satisfying a degree condition and such that it is what it has to be at the fixed point of the open stratum of the cell. This can be turned into an algorithm, I guess.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson : Thanks for the suggestion. The trouble is that there is a certain uniqueness theorem that holds (for example) for flag varieties and Grassmannians but that fails for Hessenberg varieties. This is explained for example on page 9 of Tymoczko's "Permutation actions on equivariant cohomology" https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0460.pdf In particular, if I am not mistaken, the conditions you're suggesting don't single out a unique basis for Hessenberg varieties. I suspect that BB might yield a "canonical" choice of basis, but I'm uncertain how to compute it.

Comment: ahh yes, I guess the torus isn't "big enough" and so the GKM condition fails... I'll leave my comment there in case it is useful to someone working in a different setting. Another random comment: the elements that you want to compute (or more precisely an inverse matrix) is what people call the "equivariant multiplicity". There are some things known about these rational functions (see the end of Brion's notes on equivariant cohomology and interesection theory).

Comment: To clarify, are we restricting to, say, regular semisimple elements $s$, so that the Hessenberg variety is smooth?  (Otherwise, I'm not sure how BB applies to give a basis.)

Comment: @DaveAnderson : Good point. Yes, I'm willing to assume that the Hessenberg variety is smooth.